# How to setup a Jupyter-notebook with calysto-processing to run in Binder?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, processing, android-binder

I have [jupyter-notebook](/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook) running on my own Mac with the caylsto-processing library plugged in so I can run processing scripts in a notebook in a browser tab. But I am trying to be able to run this all in binder, so that I can share my processing scripts with students during class. I created a Github repository and have it linked to a binder, and the binder builds and launches, but the only kernel available is python 3.

I have read that I can include a bunch of [configuration files](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_files.html), but I'm new to these and I don't see any examples that bring in the calysto-processing kernel, so I'm unsure on how to proceed.

Screenshot of my binder with the jupyter-notebook with a processing script - but when you click on kernels, the only kernel it shows is python:
[image: Screenshot of my binder with the jupyter-notebook with a processing script - but when you click on kernels, the only kernel it shows is python]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what steps you followed. For example, maybe post your docker extension so others can inspect what's happening.

Comment: @CelineLatulipe I think I found a workaround: check out the updated answer bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good question. Ayman suggestion is good.

I've just installed `calysto_processing` and noticed 3 things are necessary:

1. installing the `calysto_processing` package via pip,
2. running install on the `calysto_processing` package.
3. installing Processing.

First point should be easy with `requirements.txt`.

I'm unsure what the best option is for the second step (maybe a custom setup.py ?).

Step 3 feels the trickiest.

Installing Processing currently isn't supported with `apt-get` so `Dockerfile` might be way forward (even through `mybinder` recommend that only as a last resort).

Let's assume a Dockerfile would contain all the steps to manually download/install processing (and I'm not super experienced with Docker at the moment btw), it will need to be executed which will require a windowing system to render the Processing window. 
I don't know how well that plays with Docker, sounds like it's getting into virtual machine territory.

That being said, looking at the [source code right here](https://github.com/Calysto/calysto_processing/blob/master/calysto_processing/kernel.py#L156):

1. Processing is used only to validate the sketch, and pull syntax errors to display them otherwise.
2. ProcessingJS is used to actually render the processing code in a `<canvas/>` element within the Jupyter Notebook

I'm not sure what the easiest way to run the current `calysto_processing` in `mybinder` as is.

My pragmatic (even hacky if you will) suggestion is to:

1. fork the project and remove the `processing-java` dependency (which means might loose error checking)
2. install the cloned/tweaked version via pip/requirements.txt (pip can install a package from a github repo)

**Update** I have tried the above: you can run [test kernel here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/orgicus/HelloPJS/master?filepath=HelloPJS.ipynb)

[image: ProcessingJS in mybinder online shared Jupyter Notebook]

The source is [here](https://github.com/orgicus/HelloPJS) and the module is installed from [this fork](https://github.com/orgicus/calysto_processing/tree/hotfix/PJS-only-test) which simply [comments out](https://github.com/orgicus/calysto_processing/commit/709669c7c4ded588a0ba25ef40eeadbf845b0898) the `processing-java` part.

In terms of the `mybinder` configuration it boils down to:

- create a **binder** folder in the repo containing the notebook
- add **requirements.txt** which points to the tweaked version of `calysto_processing` stripped off the `processing-java` dependency: `git+https://github.com/orgicus/calysto_processing.git@hotfix/PJS-only-test`
- add **postBuild** file which runs install on the `calysto_processing` module: `python -m calysto_processing install --user`

**Notes**

- With this workaround java error checking is gone
- Although Processing syntax is used it's execute as javascript and rendered in `<canvas/>` using [ProcessingJS](http://processingjs.org/): this means no processing-java libraries, no threads or other java specific features,(buggy or no 3D),etc. just basic Processing drawing sketches
- It might be worth looking at replacing ProcessingJS with [p5.js](http://p5js.org) and checking out other JS notebooks ? (e.g. [Observable](https://observablehq.com/@d3/hierarchical-edge-bundling) or [IJavascript](https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript))

Comment: This is so incredibly helpful!!!! Thank-you, George! I will try to get this going on my own binder when I have some time over the weekend. I am going to be teaching a class that uses processing, so p5, etc. aren't useful to me.

Comment: Glad to hear it ! I'm curious about the class, if you could share your experience teaching Processing with Jupyter Notebooks that would be great ! (As I mentioned, this is limited to 2D beginner level graphics/input(mouse,keyboard), haven't tried loading images yet)). If the above answered your question feel free to tick/mark it ;)

Comment: It's a new class (new to me) that I will be teaching this fall at the University of Manitoba. I used to use Processing a lot, but I haven't ever taught it. I just think I can point students to Jupyter/Calysto-processing notebooks on Binder and they can work on activities in class and this way I don't have to worry about helping them get anything installed on their own laptops or tablets.